# Выровнять верхнее меню

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Дорогие коллеги.

1. Как сделать что, меню верхнее отображалась по центру даже чуть чуть, левее. И при этом не изменяла вид других устройств.

   - На айпаде и телефоне меню отображается корректно
   - На мониторе расположено слева
2. Как выровнять верхнюю иконку на мобильном устройстве.

[ссылка на сайт](http://stanok-pro.ru/fanvil/)

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос закрыт, нужно было меню добавить в контейнер `container`.